# which version is/are suitable for a production app for ionic CLI and Ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

As ionic 4 is released, I am wondering if I should start my new project in ionic 4 and ionic 4.9 (CLI) or any stable version you guys would suggest to prevent any issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can start your project with Ionic 4.0. With this final release, your app will perform better than version 3. Your doubt is good because there are still some bugs this is release but Ionic version 4.0 will allow you to update your application easily with the newer version. Ionic Framework team is working really hard for bug-free Ionic 4.0.

Comment: thank you for your say, as i was reading the comments it got me worried, but you are right, it should be pretty stable as ionic team mentioned. just one quick question, the ionic cli version and ionic framewoork version doesn't matter right? i can install ionic 3 framework version with the ionic 4.9 (CLI) version is it? https://blog.ionicframework.com/introducing-ionic-4-ionic-for-everyone/

Comment: Yes you can install ionic 3 with ionic 4.9(CLI) version easily.